# Google Chrome creates a HTML link although PHP echo is plain text

Tags: php, google-chrome

I try to create a trusted shops snippet with the following code:

```
echo '<!-- product reviews start -->
<!-- for each product in the basket full set of data is required -->
<span class="tsCheckoutProductItem">
'.$trustbadge[$x][2].'
<span class="tsCheckoutProductName">'.$trustbadge[$x][1].'</span>
<span class="tsCheckoutProductSKU">'.$trustbadge[$x][0].'</span>
<span class="tsCheckoutProductUrl">'.$trustbadge[$x][2].'</span>
<span class="tsCheckoutProductGTIN">'.$trustbadge[$x][3].'</span>
</span>
<!-- product reviews end -->';
```

Google Chrome creates out of line

```
<span class="tsCheckoutProductUrl">'.$trustbadge[$x][2].'</span>
```

The following:

```
<span class="tsCheckoutProductUrl"><span><a href="https://www.domain.de">https://www.domain.de</a></span></span>
```

Correct whould be:

```
<span class="tsCheckoutProductUrl">https://www.domain.de</span>
```

In Firefox the code is correct. How can I avoid that Chrome does this?

PS: The value from the array is of course without any HTML tags. Just plain text the url...

Edit 04.11.19: Here comes the code where the array is built:

```
$SQLString2 = "SELECT ObjektNr, product_url FROM tab_aktionartikel WHERE objektname='".$objekt."' AND id='".$_POST['id']."' and special_order_type=''";

$result2 = mysql_query($SQLString2);

if($result2){
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
        $objektnummer=$row2[0];
        $product_url=$row2[1];
    }
}       

$produktname=$arrOrder[$i][0];
$produktkategorie=$arrOrder[$i][5];

//Trustbadge Values in ein Array speichern
$trustbadge[$i][0]=$objektnummer;
$trustbadge[$i][1]=$produktname;
$trustbadge[$i][2]=$product_url;
```

Comment: If you view the page source, is that the outputted markup? (not in dev tools->elements tab, in the actual page source)

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Anyway, I can't reproduce your issue. If the HTML being output by PHP is exactly as you say, then Chrome does not turn it into a hyperlink. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/z98h56qx/

Comment: But the code you've shown doesn't allow us to know what your PHP is actually generating, because it's inserting values from your database, which you haven't shown us. It's good to know how the array is created, but ultimately the key thing in this question is the _content_ of the array, and we cannot see that.